# In "which" sentence, it modifies the previous sentence or the previous noun?

Tags: pronouns

> Microsoft Edge offers improvements in security and speed over Internet Explorer, which is no longer being actively developed and is available only for legacy purposes.

In this sentence, **which** modifies the noun of **Internet Explorer**.

May you tell me

1. Why does **which** not modifies the sentence of **Microsoft Edge offers improvements in security and speed over Internet Explorer**?
2. Why does **which** not modifies the noun of **Microsoft Edge** ?
3. How to confirm which **which** modify?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid you're asking three questions instead of one. You've taken the [tour] right?

Comment: @FelinusRex Are they though? Seems to me the OP's question boils down to "why does 'which' modify Internet Explorer and not Microsoft Edge?" If the OP said "how do I use relative pronouns in this sentence and why should it be in the present tense?" *then* you could argues they've asked more than one question.

Answer (score 1):

Relative pronouns, like "who", "which" and "that", modify the closest noun before them that matches (person or non-person). In this case, "which" matches "Internet Explorer" because it is the first noun before it.

Comment: Can **whichi** matches the sentence before in some sentences?

Comment: Yes, or part of the sentence before.

Comment: Please let me sort out the logic. So, **which** could modify the closest noun before it or the sentence before it, and it could not modify the noun which is not the closest. Am I right?

Comment: @Y.zeng Here in the comment section isn't the right place for a lesson on relative pronoun referents. There's plenty of information available with a search for "relative pronouns".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will do it.